# Writing null pointer to std::cout prevents later writes

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<class T> class Sample {
private:
 T val;
public:
 Sample(T InitialVal=T()) : val(InitialVal)
 {
    // do nothing
 }
 ~Sample() 
 {
    // do nothing
 }
 void PrintVal(void)
 {
     try {
    cout << "[" << val << "]" << endl;
     } catch(...) {
        cout << "exception thrown" << endl;
     }
 }
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Sample<int> ints(20), intd;
    Sample<char *> chars(const_cast<char*>("Neelakantan")), charsd;
    Sample<string> s, ss("neel");

    ints.PrintVal();
    intd.PrintVal();

    chars.PrintVal();
    charsd.PrintVal(); // <<- Culprit line. Commenting out this line works as expected.

    s.PrintVal();
    ss.PrintVal();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code, I am getting the below output:

```
sh-4.4$ g++ -o main *.cpp                                                                                                                                                       
sh-4.4$ main                                                                                                                                                                    
[20]                                                                                                                                                                            
[0]                                                                                                                                                                             
[Neelakantan]                                                                                                                                                                   
[sh-4.4$
```

When I comment out the line "`charsd.PrintVal();`", I am getting the below output:

```
[sh-4.4$ g++ -o main *.cpp                                                                                                                                                      
sh-4.4$ main                                                                                                                                                                    
[20]                                                                                                                                                                            
[0]                                                                                                                                                                             
[Neelakantan]                                                                                                                                                                   
[]                                                                                                                                                                              
[neel]                                                                                                                                                                          
sh-4.4$
```

What is the issue with the 'charsd' object of the template instance of type Sample< char *> ? No exception was thrown.

compiler version:

```
sh-4.4$ g++ --version                                                                                                                                                           
g++ (GCC) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)                                                                                                                                      
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.                                                                                                                               
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO                                                                                                      
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.                                                                                                     

sh-4.4$
```

Comment: why do you expect an exception to be thrown? In contrast to eg Java, in C++ most things that can go wrong just go wrong, they dont throw exceptions. Exceptions are expensive and you should use them for exceptional situations, not for control flow (ie make sure `val` is not `null` instead of relying on a `nullpointerexception`, which you wont get here)

Comment: @user463035818, yes either an exception or Segmentation Fault, instead of silently returning to command prompt leaves me clueless.

Comment: but thats how it works. C++ does not pretend it could make sure you write bugfree/errorfree code, but it rather constantly reminds you that you are responsible for writing correct code :P What you have there is undefined behaviour, which means the compiler is not even required to warn you about it

Comment: @user463035818 'How it works' here is just plain silly.  I comment further below.

Comment: @user463035818 Sorry guvnor, I wasn't criticising _you_.  I was complaining about the way gcc (or, rather, gcc's implementation of `ostream`) behaves here.  _That's_ what's silly.

Comment: @PaulSanders ah haha, sorry, in that case I still dont fully agree with you, but thats a different story ;).

Comment: @user463035818 No worries, it was my fault.  Confucious he say: the path to knowledge can sometimes be a painful one, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Revised answer based on new information / knowledge.  See also Jonathan Wakely's answer (I updated this before I saw that), who is a gcc / libstdc++ contributor and who picked up on the bug report I submitted.  Many thanks to him for putting me straight and sincerest apologies for making the absurd assumption that `ostream` would ever behave in the way I previously described in the first place.]

What you are actually doing, at the point of failure, is, in effect, this:

```
std::cout << (const char *) nullptr << std::endl;
```

And what most people would expect to get (although strictly speaking the behaviour of what you are doing there is undefined) would be a SEGFAULT.

`libstdc++,` however, which contains the implementation of `ostream` that `gcc` uses, does something different.  It sets `badbit` on the stream, and **only if you have enabled `badbit` exceptions** (which are disabled by default) does it (also) throw an exception. Thank you to Jonathan Wakely for pointing this out to me when I submitted a bug report about this, I knew nothing of this (and neither did anyone else posting to this thread, apparently) when I posted the first version of this answer.

But your code has not enabled said exceptions, so all that happens is that `badbit` gets set on `cout` and all subsequent writes subsequently silently fail.  I previously misinterpreted this as the program quietly exiting when nullptr was passed in but I was wrong, and I apologise to the developers for making such an unwarranted assumption.  There's more about that in the comments.

So, to get an exception thrown when this happens, you have to enable the `badbit` exception on the stream, which you can do like this:

```
std::cout.exceptions (std::ostream::badbit | std::ios::failbit);
```

Then you get the exception you were hoping for.  Personally, I don't like this behaviour much, I'd much rather have the SEGFAULT (and in fact, with clang, [you do](https://wandbox.org/permlink/icJUGxPKovQazuRI)), but Jonathan tells me it's been that way since 2002 and the developers have good reasons not to change it now.

There's a new [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3ZeST1ppyunJksbQ) showing the behaviour of `gcc` with the above line added, and the output is now:

```
[20]
[0]
[Neelakantan]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::__ios_failure'
  what():  basic_ios::clear: iostream error
[
Aborted
```

So, be warned, a trap for the unwary lies in wait there, "Why are none of my logging statements appearing all of a sudden?", or something like that.

Comment: C++ does not require that dereferencing a null pointer causes any type of exception, hardware or otherwise. It permits *any behaviour whatsoever*

Comment: Sure, but still, _naughty gcc_.

Comment: @PaulSanders, yes my expectation was segmentation fault or exception thrown up till the user code(silently it returns to the command prompt).

Comment: Yes, I don't like this 'UB can do anything' argument, certainly not as a blanket statement.  While it might be true in principle, dereferencing a null pointer has well-defined effects on all common hardware and the runtime library shouldn't just quietly suppress that behaviour.  Doing that is unreasonable, just SEGFAULT already.

Comment: @PaulSanders, Your answer helped me. Does c++ standard say that NULL pointer de-referencing be undefined (SEGFAULT, Silently terminate the Program OR something else)? At least GCC should have chosen SEGFAULT, which many are used to. Anyways thanks for you explanation and it helped.

Comment: No, there is no such guarantee, as @caleth correctly points out.  But it is not unreasonable to expect a SEGFAULT on any common platform you might expect to encounter.  Anything else requires the runtime library to do *extra* work before dereferencing the pointer, in fact, and why gcc does so here (and then apparently screws up) is anybody's guess.  It's just a great way to confuse people.  _People make mistakes_, let's not _set out_ to punish them for it.

Comment: The "absolutely anything" allows the compiler to optimise assuming that UB is never encountered, because even if it is *whatever happens* conforms to the standard. See [Undefined behavior can result in time travel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)

Comment: Including emitting code to silently exit your program when - at runtime - it encounters a NULL pointer?  I don't think so.  I could understand it if the code emitted by the _template_ did unexpected things, but that's not what happened here - [I checked](https://godbolt.org/g/TFyk1j).

Comment: When you submit that bug report to gcc it will be closed as "not a bug"

Comment: @Caleth Maybe.  Depends if they care about serving their users (and how delicately it is worded :)  Just to clarify: it's a bug (in my eyes) in the implementation of `ostream`, nothing to do with the compiler.  `clang`[works as one would expect it to](https://wandbox.org/permlink/icJUGxPKovQazuRI).

Comment: @PaulSanders, i agree the issue is with implementation of ostream, nothing to do with gcc compiler or c++ standard. ostream operator<< should have either return without printing for nullptr or de-reference blindly to generate SEGFAULT.  I think ostream operator<< is a template function which may not be possible for it to generically handle all the types. cout << (char *) 0x2000 << endl; when i ran this gcc do SEGFAULTs. only in case of nullptr/0 behavior seems to be undefined.

Comment: @Neelak Well, yes.  I`ostream` is obviously testing for `nullptr` and then bailing out.  It 'trusts' anything else, what else can it do?  `ostream operator<<` is not a template BTW.  It's an overloaded operator (and you can implement overloads of `operator<<` in your own classes as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx)).

Comment: _"and silently terminating your program for you"_ No it isn't, it's setting an error in the stream state and continuing execution of the program. The later writes fail because of the error state in the stream, so there's no more output, and then the program exits normally. **There is absolutely no "silently terminating" at all.** The program runs to completion.

Comment: @JonathonWakely Right, noted, thank you, sorry for my false assumption.  I now know that the stream sets `badbit` when it sees the null pointer so all subsequent writes fail.  But silently setting `badbit` is still unfriendly IMO, as we have been discussing [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86130).

Comment: @JonathonWakely Also, I need to apologise for making that assumption in the first place.  Why would anyone ever write code like that?  Certainly not you and it was crass of me to think so. I'm not surprised you sound a bit nettled there.

Comment: @JonathonWakely Updated my answer as promised on bugzilla. Thank you for educating me.  And sorry about the tone of some of my comments.  I can (and will) do better.

Comment: Even though Undefined Behavior may produce a rather consistent observable behavior on particular compiler in particular conditions it is typically a waste of time to investigate how exactly it leads to that sort of observable behavior.

Comment: @VTT It wasn't [a waste of time] in this case, and it was more the 'why', rather than the 'how' that interested me.  I investigated because the behaviour observed by the OP was so unusual, and I'm glad I did.  I learned something, and I don't think that what libstdc++ does here is either sensible or typical.  They're just stuck with it because it has been the way it is for a long time now and they don't dare change it.  And why did you comment here, rather than reply to my comment on your own thread?  That really breaks up the conversation.

Comment: I do agree that it would be better if library helped to detect UB or at least failed fast instead of tolerating invalid input value. But my point is that experimenting with code that causes UB and checking whether results much your expectations is not really helpful because it is wrong to have expectations about results of UB on the first place. (that gcc bug title is no good in my opinion)

Comment: @VTT You're right about the title - it's terrible - but that only happened because I badly misinterpreted the behaviour of `ostream`.  I know better now, but I think if I change the title bugzilla will create a new issue and I'm sure they'd just love me for doing that.

Comment: As for the rest, I'm sure the OP wasn't _experimenting_ with UB. He just happened to run into a rather nasty case of it and simply couldn't understand the behaviour of his code. And I'm sure he's not the only one who has done that, or will do so again. That (for me) is the real issue here.  OK, you should probably routinely set the exception handler for `badbit` but lots of people (including _everyone_ who posted to this thread, apparently, I'm not taking a pot-shot at you) don't know about it or that they have to turn it on explicitly, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that field `val;` of `charsd` object is initialized with null pointer. So attempt to pass it to `operator <<` violates operator precondition and causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah, but there's a reason for the observed behaviour, see Jonathon Wakeley's answer and my amended answer above. There usually is, with null pointers.

Answer (score 3):

`charsd` contains a null pointer, and writing a null `const char*` to an `ostream` is undefined behaviour.

GCC's implementation of the standard library checks for that condition (see [the code here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc;h=e02ba55a6262b96ead90595e1aad56119a965844;hb=HEAD#l323)) and sets the `badbit` flag in the stream state. The `badbit` indicates that the stream state has been corrupted, in this case by the unexpected null pointer that the standard says is undefined behaviour. N.B. This handling of null pointers for `ostream` is not documented and could change in future.

The program continues to run to completion, but because the `badbit` is set on the stream all the later writes fail, producing no more output on `std::cout`.

The program **does not just silently exit when the null pointer is written to the stream**. It sets an error flag, and continues running.

If you want to detect that you can do so, for example by checking the stream state at the end of `main` and printing a message to standard error:

```
int main() {
    // ...

    if (!std::cout)
        std::cerr << "An error happened while writing to cout\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Or by telling the `cout` stream that you want errors to be turned into exceptions:

```
int main() {

    std::cout.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Now the program will throw an exception as soon as the error happens:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure[abi:cxx11]'
  what():  basic_ios::clear: iostream error
Aborted (core dumped)
```